# Close keyboard with Side Menu MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm using MMDrawerController as a side menu. I can't find where to close the keyboard in center view when I open the side menu.

I've tried

1. write `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in `sideMenuViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method.
2. `addObserver` in `centerViewController` which called `[self.view endEditing:YES]` and `postObserver` in `sideMenuViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method.

It just don't work and cause like this...

[image]

Anyone has an idea to fix it?

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES] this is correct. But you are using this method in wrong place. Use this method in your main view controller view will disapper

Comment: sadly viewWillDisAppear won't get called in my case. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

In your CentralView controller

```
#pragma mark - Button Handlers
-(void)leftDrawerButtonPress:(id)sender{
    [self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Try this method. It is working for me

Comment: Yes it works! Do you know why `[self.view endEditing:YES]` can't work?

Comment: Sorry @Jenny I don't have any idea. Maybe different views. I am not sure. I am also searching. :)

Comment: This is not really a complete solution since you can also open the drawer with swipe gestures.

Comment: @MihaiDamian check out my solution on the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

today I met the same problem :)

I have spend several hours debugging the MMDrawer library and I have found solution of some kind. My solutions contains of two steps:

1) In `MMDrawerController.m` file - in the implementation of method: `-(void)toggleDrawerSide:(MMDrawerSide)drawerSide animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion` add at the beginning of the method, the following code: `[self.centerViewController.view endEditing:true];`. With this code you close the keyboard when tapping on menu burger - all views that are subviews for the current centerViewController try to resignFirstResponder.

2) In `MMDrawerController.m` file - in the implementation of method: `-(void)panGestureCallback:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture` replace the else statement of case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan with the following code:

```
else {
     //hide keyboard when pan gesture start
     [self.centerViewController.view endEditing:true];

     self.startingPanRect = self.centerContainerView.frame;
}
```

And I am giving you the old code - coming from the library just for more detail explanation:

```
else {
     self.startingPanRect = self.centerContainerView.frame;
}
```

With this code you close the keyboard when starting pan gesture, if such pan gesture is allowed for side menu - all views that are subviews for the current centerViewController try to resignFirstResponder.

P.S. I have tried to put this code in another method, but it behave a little strange because of the animation completion block after the movement of the centerViewController is done. So I think `endEditing:` in the beginning of the pan gesture is the way to go.

Hope that could help you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a use observer for this, just have IBOutlet property for your UITextField say "textfield".

```
[self.textfield resignFirstResponder];
```

add this line when you sideMenuViewController's viewWillAppear.

Comment: Textfield is in centerViewController. How can I connect textfield in storyboard to sideMenuViewController?

Comment: I still use observer and post observer in sideMenuViewController's viewWillAppear. It works!!! Why can't `[self.view endEditing]` work?

Comment: I don't thing that the subviews methods will automatically get call when editing property of self.view gets changes. properties of subviews might get change like tableview.editing but resignFirstResponder of textfield will not be same

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still has problems with opening the drawer using a gesture, use the following code:

Put the code where you initialize your drawer controllers.

```
[self.drawerController setGestureCompletionBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, UIGestureRecognizer *gesture) {
            // hide the keyboard when the gesture completes
            if(drawerController.openSide == MMDrawerSideLeft) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
            }
        }];
```